# UITapGestureRecognizer work for just first three elements of a loop

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using several loops to create a sub menu on 3 levels, by assigning a `UIGestureRecognizer` to a `UILabel`. I get some very strange behaviour; in any case the event is thrown only for the first three elements of my menu. No matter if they are on level 2, 3, or both. I have tried with `UIButton` instead of `UILabel` and I get the exact same behaviour.

The `UILabel` are added to some `UIView` who are inside a `UIScrollView`.

Here is the code:

```
    for(NSDictionary* sub in [category objectForKey:@"sub"]) {
    // First level
    if([sub valueForKey:@"sub"]) {
        // Second level
        for(NSDictionary* sub2 in [sub objectForKey:@"sub"]) {                
            // Third level (links)
            for(NSDictionary __strong *video in [sub2 objectForKey:@"video"]) {
                // Label handler tap
                labelCat.tag = i;
                labelCat.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
                [videos insertObject:[[video objectForKey:@"src"] objectForKey:@"text"] atIndex:i]; i++;
                singleFingertap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(showVideo:)];
                [labelCat addGestureRecognizer:singleFingertap];
                [view3 addSubview:labelCat];
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Label handler tap
        labelCat.tag = i;
        [videos insertObject:[[video objectForKey:@"src"] objectForKey:@"text"] atIndex:i]; i++;
        singleFingertap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(showVideo:)];
        labelCat setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [labelCat addGestureRecognizer:singleFingertap];
    }
}
```

And for the action handler:

```
- (void)showVideo:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"test");
}
```

Do you have any idea of what's happening here ?
Thanks

Comment: When you say you tried with a `UIButton`, did you still use the `UITapGestureRecognizer`? Use `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` with the `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` control event.

Comment: Yes I tried this way, but it was exactly the same: the TouchUpInside event worked for first three buttons, then nothing.

Comment: Is your scrollview's contentSize and frame right ?

Comment: Yes i just checked both, size is correct. And my labels appear as expected, they are just not tapable after the 3rd one.

Comment: Like Templar, I think the cause is either the buttons being out of bounds of their containing view or some other tappable view obscuring the buttons and eating their events.

Comment: In your code I can't see where you are creating new labels/buttons. Maybe you're reusing the same button?

Comment: Thanks Templar and Jesper, it was indeed an issue with the sub view frame height. ScrollView height was ok, but not view1 height, even if labels outside of frame wasn't hidden. Changing views height solved the problem.